# Prestashop facebook share text

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, embed, share, prestashop

Hello please help me: if I paste link of my site to facebook message, facebook processes it to thumbnail + some text. There is text "Shop powered by PrestaShop". How do I change it?

[image]

Prestashop version 1.6.1.4. 
Site address : http://myfleur.cz/

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's crawler scrapes the HTML of the URL that is shared. On a regular HTML page (similar to your case) this content is basic and may be incorrect, because the scraper has to guess which content is important, and which is not.

The good news is that you can take control of what the Facebook crawler picks up from each page by using [Open Graph meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup). These tags provide structured info about the page such as the title, description, preview image, and more.

So just add these meta tags in your homepage:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<your-webpage-url>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<new-title>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<new-image-url>" />
```

(You can add other meta tags also as mentioned in the link mentioned)

P.S. You can use [this url to debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmyfleur.cz%2F), which content facebook is scraping from your website.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The solution in that case is go to 
Preferences -> SEO & URLs -> index (edit)
and change there the Meta-Description.